# Position of PDF element using itext7

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to get the position of Paragraph in pdf file.

Right now I get it at pdf generation time, by getting the current position before/after adding the paragraph to the document. And then I use that position to edit.

1. Is there **easy** way to find location of paragraphs, **after** the pdf is generated?
2. Should I stop using paragraphs and position, and switch to template with AcroForms for filling in data programatically?

Everything works, but It feels like ive selected the wrong approach.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As we don't know your requirements, it's difficult to recommend something. As long as you generate the PDFs to edit yourself and know the positions in the document to edit, you can of course make use of that knowledge and edit at the known positions. Otherwise, though, using AcroForm form fields is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I pretty much got what I needed to hear.